# React Native auto open an app screen on API request, Just like whatsapp / Viber receiving a phone call

Tags: react-native

please be kindly let me know how to manage auto open an app using react native. For an example same workaround like Viber receives a phone call request. I want to know what is the technology that viber or whatsapp using to manage on call request pop up the application.

Comment: I am also looking for such functionality for taxi booking app. I guess they use some sort of push notification. I am try FCM along with voip notification for ios.

Comment: Hey did you find the solution?